# Can the HTTP version of response differ from the HTTP version of the request

Tags: http, connection, webserver, rfc

If I use curl to get a websites data it sends this packet header (with an empty body):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: someurl.com
Accept: */*
```

HTTP version 1.1 is used here.

My question: could it happen that a server answers with a 200 OK Response with a different HTTP version. E.g.:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
...
```